# Sending `onInstallConversionDataLoaded` with no listeners registered AppsFlyer

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, deep-linking, appsflyer

I get the error

> Sending `onInstallConversionDataLoaded` with no listeners registered

when trying to unmount the InstallConversion listener from AppsFlyer. Here is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import appsFlyer from 'react-native-appsflyer';
import NonRenderOnChangeData from '../nonRenderOnChangeData/NonRenderOnChangeData';
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

function AppsFlyerHandler({ navigation }) {
  useFocusEffect(() => {
   // Configure listeners before initializing SDK
      const onInstallConversionDataCanceller = appsFlyer.onInstallConversionData(
      (res) => {
        console.log("res", res);
        if (JSON.parse(res.data.is_first_launch) == true) {
          if (res.data.af_status === 'Non-organic') {
            if (NonRenderOnChangeData.userIsEligableForCampaign()) {
              this.props.navigation.navigate('LoadingPage', {entitlementID: res.data.campaign});
            }
            console.log('This is first launch and a Non-Organic install. Media source: ' + media_source + ' Campaign: ' + campaign);
          } else if (res.data.af_status === 'Organic') {
            console.log('This is first launch and a Organic Install');
          }
        } else {
            console.log('This is not first launch');
        }
      }
    );

    const onAppOpenAttributionCanceller = appsFlyer.onAppOpenAttribution((res) => {
      if ("deep_link_value" in res.data) {
        if (NonRenderOnChangeData.userIsEligableForCampaign()) {
          this.props.navigation.navigate('LoadingPage', {entitlementID: res.data.deep_link_value});
        }
      }
    });

    // Initialize AppsFlyer here
    appsFlyer.initSdk(
      {
        devKey: 'xxxxxxxx',
        isDebug: true,
        appId: 'xxxxxxx',
        onInstallConversionDataListener: true,
      },
      (result) => {
        console.log("AppsFlyer Init",result);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error("AppsFlyer Init",error);
      }
    );

    return () => {
      onInstallConversionDataCanceller();
      onAppOpenAttributionCanceller();
    };
  }); 

  return null;
}

export default AppsFlyerHandler;
```

I have tried following all guides and documentation but still seem to get this warning no matter how I do it. I have tried to remove the listener the same way as the documentation, like down below, but still get the same warning. Does anybody know a solution?

```
 if (onInstallConversionDataCanceller) {
 onInstallConversionDataCanceller();
 console.log('unregister onInstallConversionDataCanceller');
 onInstallConversionDataCanceller = null;
 }
 if (onAppOpenAttributionCanceller) {
 onAppOpenAttributionCanceller();
 console.log('unregister onAppOpenAttributionCanceller');
 onAppOpenAttributionCanceller = null;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to disable this feature and you want the yellow warning to go away, you can set the `initSdk` `options` option `onInstallConversionDataListener` to `false` like so:

```
options = {
    isDebug: false,
    devKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    onInstallConversionDataListener: false, //Optional
    onDeepLinkListener: true, //Optional
    timeToWaitForATTUserAuthorization: 10, //for iOS 14.5
    appId: 'xxxxxxxxx',
};
```

You can also probably learn a lot more about this from the demo app:
https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/appsflyer-react-native-plugin/blob/df985ace2f67f829811880a3a971ad6352d4272c/demos/appsflyer-react-native-app/components/AppsFlyer.js